# How to retrieve album images using Facebook php SDK?

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to retrieve images from Facebook album using PHP SDK.

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
$user_id = $user_profile['id'];
$albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums');
print_r($albums);
foreach($albums['data'] as $album)
{
    $album_id = $album['id'];
    echo $album_id;
    $photos = $facebook->api('/{$album_id}/photos');

}
foreach($photos['data'] as $photo)
    {
        echo "<img src='{$photo['source']}'/>","<br/>";
    }
```

But it retrieves an empty array.When I tried to print a certain i, in the first loop,I found that code in that loop is not executed. So what wrong would I be doing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, see below

```
$albums = $facebook->api('/me/photos');
```

i think It should be like that.

Comment: Tried that too!!!But same result with an empty array.Still not entering the loop.